# Use a macro to copy master data based on critera to different (multiple) sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a tracking workbook for new construction. I have a macro set to add more bids to a master sheet, but I need that master data to be copied to their respective sheets based on the criteria of builder (about 20 different builders) to the next empty row. I used another question on this site to modify code, but it's not working to my satisfaction. Here's the data I'm looking at:

Job           Builder
2015    Other
2015    AdvancedBuilding
2015    BullardHomes
2015    CodyWest
2015    DublinHomes
2015    DurationBuilders
2015    EGGonzales
2015    JanFrentzen
2015    McFallBuilders
2015    NewGeneration
2015    ONeilConstruction
2015    PridgenHomes
2015    ProfessionalBuilders 
2015    RERobinson
2015    Robinshore
2015    Rutenberg
2015    Spain&Cooper
2015    Tremattera
2015    VisionConstruction
2015    WarringHomes
2015    Other

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sBuilder As String
Dim wsRow as Long
Worksheets("MasterData").Activate
r = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
c = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'find last column
Range("B1:B").AutoFilter
For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "MasterData" Then
'*edited to accommodate pre-existing data
ws.Activate '*activate sheet so you can use Cells() with it
wsRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1 '*find first usable row in ws
sFruit = ws.Name 'criteria to look for    
Worksheets("MasterData").Activate 'bring focus back to main sheet    
Range("B1:B" & r).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sBuilder    
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(r, c)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Range("A" & wsRow)    
End If    
Next ws
Range("B1").AutoFilter
```

Comment: What is unsatisfactory about it? It's hard to help when we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I apologize, I'm receiving an error "Autofilter of range class failed". I adjusted the range from Range("B1:B" & r) to Range("B" & r), but the data was deleted. The columns were filtered however.

Comment: The error occurs on this line: `Range("B1:B" & r).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sBuilder`?  What do you mean by "but the data was deleted"?

Comment: Correct. The data was supposed to be copied to the their respective sheets with the builder names. However, after running the macro, the data from the MasterData sheet disappeared.

Comment: I already have sheets created with those builder names in the data.

Comment: Are those sheets names the same name as the builder on it? you will need something to track that sheet down someway to link that sheet name to the builder she is related

Comment: Yes, @YgorYansz I used a dropdown list for the builder names when adding jobs to the MasterData sheet to avoid typos. The sheet names match the dropdown list for builders as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're trying to filter on a blank Criteria1

```
sFruit = ws.Name 'criteria to look for    
Worksheets("MasterData").Activate 'bring focus back to main sheet    
Range("B1:B" & r).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sBuilder
```

You assign the name of the worksheet to `sFruit` which isn't declared in your code (be sure use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of all your code modules to ensure typos don't creep into variable names), then you use `sBuilder` as the criteria for your `.AutoFilter`, but haven't assigned anything to it.

I doubt that this is causing the data on your `MasterData` sheet to be deleted, but it would filter out all the values, since none would be equal to the blank `sBuilder`.

Some suggestions to simplify your code a bit, since my guess is that you started with Macro Recorder code (which is often an excellent place to start!). By assigning your `MasterData` worksheet to a variable, you can reference it directly instead of having to constantly switch visible worksheets.

```
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sBuilder As String
Dim wsRow as Long
Dim wsMaster as Worksheet

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set wsMaster = Worksheets("MasterData")
' .UsedRange is a simple, built in way to get the total
r = wsMaster.UsedRange.Rows.count
c = wsMaster.UsedRange.Columns.Count
'Range("B1:B").AutoFilter
For Each ws In Worksheets
  If ws.Name <> "MasterData" Then
  '*edited to accommodate pre-existing data
    'ws.Activate '*activate sheet so you can use Cells() with it
    '*find first usable row in ws
    wsRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    sMaster = ws.Name 'criteria to look for    
    'Worksheets("MasterData").Activate 'bring focus back to main sheet    
    wsMaster.Range("B1:B" & r).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sBuilder    
    'add code here to ensure "builderName" is a valid worksheet 
    wsMaster.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(r,c)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
              ws.Range("A" & wsRow)    
  End If    
Next ws
'Range("B1").AutoFilter
```

Ygor has a very valid point, that if you have a builder name who doesn't have a sheet, the copy will fail, but I believe that it will give a different error than the one you're seeing. I've added a comment to the code on where you would want to put that check.

Comment: I forgot to remove the "Fruit"!  Thank you very much for the assistance FreeMan. I will test this after my lunch.

Comment: I'm receiving an error now that the object variable or with block variable is not set for this line: `wsMaster = Worksheets("MasterData")`. I adjusted it to `Worksheets("MasterData").Activate` , but now I'm getting the same error message with this line: `r = wsMaster.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: bah! I often forget the `Set`. I've updated the 2nd line of 'actual' code (after the `Dim` statements) above with this line; `Set wsMaster = Worksheets("MasterData")`.

Comment: Can you take a look at this one more time for the following code: `wsMaster = ws.Name` It's giving an error that this object doesn't support this property or method. I apologize for the continuous questions, but I'm relatively new to using macros.

Comment: I have another sheet named ActiveJobStatus that the ws.Name is referencing somehow. When I hover over the highlighted error, it gives me this code: `ws.Name = "ActiveJobStatus"`

Comment: You need to change the line of code you referenced 2 comments up - I left out the keyword `Set` from the original code. In the comment above, `ws.name` will, at some point during code execution, refer to _every_ worksheet in your workbook. that's what `For Each ws In Worksheets` does. If you don't want it to process that worksheet, update the `If` statement right after the `For Each`.